How can I override a custom domain in GitHub Pages to add a generic GitHub.io domain type?
I bought a custom domain miguelmaidebezares.com which is essentially my name. However I would like to create a repository on which I will collaborate with other people, and don't want the website deployed on a URL that uses my name. I am trying to deploy it in "repo_name".github.io but so far could not find how.
I have tried deleting the repository and adding a new one, but have the same issue and my repository is deployed in http://miguelmaidebezares.com/zummybears/.
GitHub's support pages exactly describe my issue:

Using a custom domain across multiple repositories
If you set a custom domain for a user or organization site, by
default, the same custom domain will be used for all project sites
owned by the same account. For more information about site types, see
"About GitHub Pages."
For example, if the custom domain for your user site is
www.octocat.com, and you have a project site with no custom domain
configured that is published from a repository called octo-project,
the GitHub Pages site for that repository will be available at
www.octocat.com/octo-project.
You can override the default custom domain by adding a custom domain
to the individual repository.

Note: The URLs for project sites that are privately published are not affected by the custom domain for your user or organization site.
For more information about privately published sites, see "Changing
the visibility of your GitHub Pages site" in the GitHub Enterprise
Cloud documentation.

To remove the default custom domain, you must remove the custom domain
from your user or organization site.


As that screenshot (why a screenshot?!) tells you, you have to override it with another custom domain. There's no way to revert to the default github.io domain - "To remove the default custom domain, you must remove the custom domain from your user or organization site."
